# Error when i use Yarn for install dependencies

Tags: vue.js, dependencies, hadoop-yarn

When I use yarn for install dependencies of my Vue project get this error:

```
error Couldn't find package "loader-utils@^1.4.0" required by "babel-loader@^8.0.5" on the "npm" registry.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Couldn't find package "loader-utils@^1.2.3" required by "webpack@^4.0.0" on the "npm" registry.
    at MessageError.ExtendableBuiltin (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:721:66)
    at new MessageError (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:750:123)
    at PackageRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:36539:17)
    at Generator.throw (<anonymous>)
    at step (/usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:310:30)
    at /usr/local/Cellar/yarn/1.22.4/libexec/lib/cli.js:323:13
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

how can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

npm install loader-utils --save-dev